# Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation. No such process

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

**Early Situation**

`Socket.IO` framework used in my project and i tried to run my project. till yesterday it's works fine. so it throw error like socket.io written in objective-c show it need to run obj-c header. than i found one more error, which writes no architecture include arm-64 than i tried to re run and it suggest use rosetta simulator so i select it and run but project got stuck and showed running in process. so i just removed rosetta than restart pc and tried to run with apple silicon simulator.

**Present Situation**

every time i tried to run with ]apple silicon simulator it shows me this message.

[image]

**simulator detail i got**

```
Details

Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-07-28 05:29:36 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "launchApplicationWithID:options:pid:error:";
}
--
Application launch for 'com.lb.TVRemote' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone15,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.4 (20E247)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 598;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator16.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.3.1 (a) (Build 22E772610a)
Xcode 14.3 (21812) (Build 14E222b)
Timestamp: 2023-07-28T10:59:36+05:30
```

want to run app on simulator.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you change something "yesterday"?

Comment: i seen rossetta pop up and select it. now i am trying to run but not running @soundflix

Comment: @JatinBhuva just uninstall rosetta for now. it's temporary solution because i didn't find how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue when am running on release mode with simulators, now it works fine after switched to debug mode